# grails foreign key for unidirectional one to one

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

In grails document, http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#cascades

For unidirectional one to one mapping,

> In the case of a unidirectional one-to-one association that defines a belongsTo then the cascade strategy is set to "ALL" for the owning side of the relationship (A->B) and "NONE" from the side that defines the belongsTo (B->A)

I understand this, but just wondering where is the foreign key, is that in the owning side or the other side?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use dbconsole to see the generated tables, go to: yourapp/dbconsole and put the `DataSource.groovy` info to login.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of belongsTo(B->A) the foreign key is kept on B as a_id.